# "Why anyone would do X is beyond me." vs. "Why would anyone do X is beyond me.": which one is the proper sentence construction?

Tags: sentence-construction, difference

Which the sentence construction is correct among the following two sentences?

- "Why **anyone would** do X is beyond me."
- "Why **would anyone** do X is beyond me."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version is correct. It's an indirect question:

[Thoughtco *indirect question*](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-an-indirect-question-1691162)

> A declarative sentence that reports a question and ends with a period rather than a question mark. Contrast with a direct question.
> **In Standard English, there is no inversion of normal word order in indirect questions: e.g., "I asked him if he was going home."**

[emphasis added]